# Java runtime exec

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to convert various xls files into csv. when I execute the following command in the terminal it works fine

```
    libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv --outdir 
/Data/edennis/ /Data/edennis/2013-10/*.xls
```

but when I try with runtime exec it does not.

**Research I've done:**

1. According to this thread [Java Runtime exec() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929015/java-runtime-exec-behavior) cannot execute system commands like echo, but libreoffice is not a system command, isn't it an executable program ?
2. [Java runtime exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223030/java-runtime-exec)This thread recommends to use processBuilder, but not sure if this is what I would need  to do in my case.
3. According to the [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29):

> EXEC:
>   Executes the specified string command in a separate process with the
>   specified environment.

Comment: Is there any error you'd like to share with us?

Comment: How do you call it? Perhaps you have to give full path to the executable file?

Comment: @piet.t no error, it doesnt break it runs through but it doesnt execute..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no reason why Runtime.exec should not be able to run /bin/echo (if available).

Second, yes, use ProcessBuilder.

Third, your problems stem from using shell syntax for file patterns like `*.xls`. Runtime.exec calls the program you specify, not  a shell that would do filename expansion. If you need to do filename expansion, run a shell like:

```
"sh -c libreoffice --blabla *.xls"
```

Comment: it worked thanks! I had to use a String array but otherwise worked fine.